# What is the method of doing nl2br in Genshi?

Tags: python, pylons, genshi

hiyas. I using Genshi+Pylons.

please teach me, how use \n to <br/>tag in Genshi?

I hope to obtain the same result as "**nl2br**" in php to change line. 
Or, does not the solution exist?

i'm assign template to some text.

```
(genshi template)
<p>${c.message}</p>
```

Im tried. 
case 1:

```
(python code)
c.message = """
foo
bar
"""
```

NG. display result is "foo bar"

case 2:

```
(python code)
c.message = """
foo<br />
bar

"""
```

NG. display result is "foo<br />bar". 
displayed escaped stirings!
It was a same deal as <br/> as for <br />.

Postscript. 
I want to avoid using the pre tag.

thanks.
When it is not easy to read because it is not good, I'm sorry by English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<py:for each="line in message.split('\n')">${line}<br /></py:for>
```

Comment: TankYou piquadrat. it worked!

I wish sincerely to express our gratitude for your wisdom.